# What is difference between pymodbus and pymodbus3 modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymodbus, pymodbus3

Hope you are doing great! I recently started using python for modbus communication. I want to clear my few doubts.

1. What module is better for modbus implementation using Python - minimalmodbus, pymodbus, pymodbus3 or else.
2. **I am using python3.4** but unable to install pymodbus module using pip or any means. So **I installed pymodbus3**.
3. While using pymodbus3 module, I was able to write coils using following code:

   ```
   import pymodbus3
   import serial
   from pymodbus3.pdu import ModbusRequest
   from pymodbus3.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient 
   from pymodbus3.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer
   from serial.tools.list_ports import comports

   client = ModbusClient(method = "rtu", port = 'COM4',stopbits = 1, bytesize = 8, parity = 'N', baudrate= 19200)
   connection = client.connect()
   client.write_coil(1000, 1, unit = 0x01)
   ```

For reading coil status (function 0x01):

```
result = client.read_coils(1000,1)
print(result)
client.close()
```

Its returning None.

Or writing to register and reading is also not working:

```
client.write_register(0, 1000, unit=0x01)
resu= client.read_holding_registers(0, 1, unit=0x01)
print(resu)
client.close()
```

*Positive response is welcomed!*

Comment: I believe that `pymodbus3` is a Python 3 version of `pymodbus`. I also commend your style of asking questions, detailed and specific with no doubt about what's being asked. Really good job on that.

Comment: Thanks for appreciation Koga! So can we refer the documentation for [pymodbus](http://pythonhosted.org/pymodbus/) for pymodbus3.

Comment: umodbus module is also not working for me, I tried the example in [docs](http://umodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/rtu.html#example)

Comment: umm..I am using minimalmodbus which is supportingall the functions and i Implemented my features with it. But it was not able to use Force write multiple coils function. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a rather old question, but I want to put this information out there so there is less confusion.

`pymodbus3` was a fork of `pymodbus` created to support python3 before `pymodbus` did so. `pymodbus` now fully supports python3 and `pymodbus3` is no longer maintained and does not have all the latest that the original does.

See https://github.com/uzumaxy/pymodbus3/issues/7 for details.